# HTML read javascript and put result into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spotify

I'm new to HTML/javascript and I want to make something that displays Last.FM current playing songs, into a div on html, which displays it in text, I have a code that sends the current song through a chat on www.irccloud.com, and I was wondering If you could change it so that It could get received and put into a DIV on a page, the code is below:

and var r is the completed code, so how would I do something in the div that picks up the source as the link above and then grabs var r from it? If so, how would I do it??

I have tried the following code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7VCck/)

Sorry if I do not make sense.

```
(function () {
            var e = "DeviousRunner";
            window.lfmRecentTrack = function (t) {
                var n = (new Array).concat(t.recenttracks.track)[0];
                    var album, spurl;
                    if (n.album["#text"]) {
                        album = " (from " + n.album["#text"] + ")";
                    } else {
                        album = "";
                    }
                    try {
                        var spotify = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        spotify.open("GET", "https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=" + encodeURIComponent(n.artist["#text"] + " - " + n.name), false);
                        spotify.send();
                        var spotresp = JSON.parse(spotify.responseText);
                        if (spotresp["tracks"].length > 0) {
                            //var urisplit = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"].split(":");
                            //spurl = " https://open.spotify.com/" + urisplit[1] + "/" + urisplit[2];
                            spurl = spotresp["tracks"][0]["href"];
                        } else {
                            console.log("spotify: couldn't get url");
                            spurl = "";
                        }
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.log("spotify: " + e.message);
                        spurl = "";
                    }
                    var r = "is listening to " + n.name + " by " + n.artist["#text"] + " " + album + " (" + spurl + ")";
            }
            var n = document.createElement("script");
            n.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            n.setAttribute("src", "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=" + e + "&api_key=dd5fb083b94a7196cf696b9d7d11bc63&limit=1&format=json&callback=window.lfmRecentTrack");
            document.body.appendChild(n)
        })();
```

Comment: You probably wanted innerHTML not html: document.getElementById('rss').innerHTML(r);

Answer (score 0):

I updated your **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7VCck/2/)**,
by moving this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("rss");
    element.innerHTML = r;
```

inside the function...


***hope this is useful for you***